# How to use Open SSL lib to encrypt/decrypt my own connection data

Tags: c++, ssl, encryption, cryptography

My C++ application creates a TCP connection to a remote server.
I need the full control over this connection (creating the connection, receiving data, sending data). However, the remote server expects SSL encryption. How can I get use of Open SSL library to encrypt and decrypt the data stream in both directions (going out and coming in), while my application handling the whole communication?

### My app to remote server

(my app data) -> [encrypt by openssl] -> (encrypted data) -> (my app sends data to remote server)

### Remote server to my app

(remote server) -> (my app receives encrypted data) -> [decrypt by openssl] -> (text message to my app)

I need to get only those within square brackets above to be done by the open SSL library. Rest will be handled by my code. I can provide my private key and public key to the open SSL library. Please note that I cannot use BIO_read() and BIO_write() functions. When the open SSL lib provides encrypted data, my code will send it to the server, and vice versa.

Also, I would like to know how to do the same, in case if my application is the server, and a remote client connects to me with SSL. I will be having the certificate.

Thanks,
Wishwa.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far? Have you checked any relevant documentation?

Comment: I think you need to have a look at BIO_s_mem and SSL_set_bio, e.g. have not a socket but your own memory based BIO as the backend. Also, the man page of BIO_s_bio might help, it describes a scenario similar to yours.